# How to make initial authenticated request with token from local storage?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I'm using vanilla flux with some `utils` for communicating with my APIs.

On initial page load I'd like to read some token from local storage and then make a request to my API to get my data.

I've got a `LocalStorageUtils.js` library for interacting with `window.localStorage`. My container component handles all login/logout actions and reads the current user on page load.

`App.js`

```
componentWillMount() {
  LocalStorageUtils.get('user');
}
```

`LocalStorageUtils` reads the value and brings it into Flux via `ServerAction` similar to the [flux chat example](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/examples/flux-chat/js/utils/ChatWebAPIUtils.js#L51).

```
get(key) {
  var value = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
  if (value) { 
    ServerActionCreators.receiveFromLocalStorage(key, value); 
  }
}
```

That puts the user into my `UserStore` and into my views where I can show the username and some logout link, etc.

I also have `ApiUtils.js` for requesting data from the server. So the question is: Where do I tell my `ApiUtils` that I have a logged-in user at initial page load?

I could call some method inside `ApiUtils` from my `LocalStorageUtils` but that does not feel right.
Or do I have to make another round trip whenever I get a change event inside my container component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works and feels right.

As getting data from local storage is synchronous there is no need to pipe it through Flux via `ServerActionCreators`. Simply use `LocalStorageUtils` to get the current user and call the `login` method with that user. The `login` Action is the same you would use when a user initially logs in. `login` triggers getting new data from server. The new data is saved in my `DataStore` and the user is saved to my `UserStore`.

Thanks for all hints at Twitter and at https://reactiflux.slack.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the user as data to your `ApiUtils` class and removing the need from being concerned about how your `ApiUtils` is used.

```
var ApiUtils = function () {
   this.get = function (endpoint, data) {
      return theWayYouSendAjaxRequests.get(endpoint).setData(data);
   };
};

// Wherever your ApiUtils is used.
var api = new ApiUtils();
api.get('/me', {user: userFromStore});
```

Comment: Where and when would you get the user? And how would you put it into Flux?